# How to create query-wide table alias in db2?

Tags: sql, db2

I have the following query. What I'm trying to accomplish is update the c_id field of table ssa.psa_xtn with the c_id field of ccc.p_s_a where the a_id's of both tables match.

```
update ssa.psa_xtn xtn
    set xtn.c_id =
    (
        select psa.c_id
        from ccc.p_s_a psa 
        inner join ssa.psa_xtn xtn 
        on psa.a_id = xtn.a_id
    )
    where psa.a_id = xtn.a_id;
```

I'm getting an error that says psa.a_id is not valid in the context used(last line). I understand that this is because psa is defined in the subquery. How can I define it for the entire query or even define it again in the main query so that this query becomes valid?

Comment: Does db2 support this syntax:  update table1 set field = table2.field from table1 join table2 etc?

Comment: unfortunately it does not, which makes me quite angry.

Answer (score 1):

You need a correlated subselect, as @IanBjorhovde mentioned:

```
update ssa.psa_xtn xtn
    set xtn.c_id =
    (
        select psa.c_id
        from ccc.p_s_a psa 
        where psa.a_id = xtn.a_id
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider looking at the `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO ssa.psa_xtn xtn
   using ccc.p_s_a psa
   on (xtn.a_id = psa.a_id)
   when matched then update set xtn.c_id = psa.c_id;
```

It offers a lot more flexibility that a correlated subselect, and also provides the ability to perform upserts (update else insert).

Comment: The problem with the original SQL is that the subselect is _not_ correlated.

Comment: LOL!  Not sure where my brain was on that.  Editing my answer to just encapsulate `MERGE`.